# Error SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to create a filter between two tables with different schemas in postgresql with the query builder laravel

the first table named **Customer_clinet** is in the **master schema** with columns: `id, customer_id, and vendor_id`

the second table named **vendors** is in a **public schem**a with `columns: id, name, type, status`

I want to make a filter for example if I input in the controller ClientVendor@filter :

```
'client_id' = 1
'status' = active
'type' = marketplace
```

then automatically filter the data in the schema master in the vendor table

```
    $users = DB::table('master.clients_vendor')
            ->join('public.vendors', 'vendor_id.id', '=', 'vendors.id')
            ->get();
            return response()->json($users);
```

in my controller just trying to connect between tables but an error message appears

Comment: you are joining 2 DB, which is not common, can try reading this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-properly-use-2-database-relationships

Comment: The statement "error message appears" is totally useless. It's like I answered "fix the error". Doesn't do you any good at all. **Post the error.**   ---   @amo5mhz This is not a join of 2 DBs. It's a join between 2 schema in the same DB, which is not uncommon at all.